# Can't connect local consul agent to server running inside Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, consul

I've got a Consul server running inside a VM with client agents running on other VMs, all inside Vagrant.

The client agents running on other VMs all register with the Consul server no problem.

I'm trying to run a client agent on my local machine for local development purposes. However, I can't get the client agent to connect to the Vagrant instance of Consul. I've tried combinations of **public** and **private** network and port forwarding but I can't get it right.

How can I configure the Vagrantfile / Consul client to register?

**Stripped down Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  consul_servers = ["consul1"]

  consul_servers.each.with_index(1) do |consul_server, index|
    config.vm.define consul_server do |server|
      server.vm.box = "centos/7"
      server.vm.box_version = "1809.01"
      # vars['consul'][consul_server]['hostname'] is set to "consul1"
      server.vm.hostname = vars['consul'][consul_server]['hostname']

      # vars['consul'][consul_server]['ip_address'] is set to 192.168.23.17
      server.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: vars['consul'][consul_server]['ip_address']
      server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8500, host: "850#{index}"

      # I've tried with these forwarded ports as well. 
      # Leaving them here for info
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8300, host: 8310
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8301, host: 8311, protocol: "tcp"
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8301, host: 8311, protocol: "udp"
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8302, host: 8311, protocol: "tcp"
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8302, host: 8311, protocol: "udp"
      # server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8400, host: 8410

      server.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
        # ...
    end
  end
end
```

**Consul Server config:**

```
datacenter        = "dc1"
data_dir          = "/opt/consul"
server            = true
bootstrap_expect  = 1
ui                = true
client_addr       = "0.0.0.0"
retry_join        = ["192.168.23.17"]
bind_addr         = "192.168.23.17"
```

**Consul client config (running locally)**

```
datacenter        = "dc1"
data_dir          = "/consul/data"
retry_join        = ["192.168.23.17"] # Tried "localhost", "0.0.0.0"
node_name         = "local-dev"
bind_addr         = "192.168.23.1" # This is the IP for the vboxnet1 interface.
# For bind_addr I've also tried 192.168.1.12 (en0 ip address), localhost, 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal Vagrant file and Consul configuration to help reproduce the problem?

Comment: @bagljas Added config.

Comment: when doing port mapping from Guest to Host in Vagrantfile, make sure that you either map to the same port i.e. guest `8300` -> host `8300`, or add host port to which you mapped `8300` to the Consul client configuration, in you case `8310`. Also make sure you are able to connect to these ports e.g. using `telnet`. If you are unable to connect to TCP port 8310 via `telnet 192.168.23.17 8310` Consul client running locally will not be able to do it either.